# How to transform results from a dictionary in python into excel?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

hi I have results from a strategy I am running in the following format:

```
2013-12-27 00:00:00: {'SPX': 1841.4, 'SPTR': 3302.66, ..., 'prev_day_rate': 0.08}
...
2015-12-27 00:00:00: {'SPX': 1841.4, 'SPTR': 3302.66,..., 'prev_day_rate': 0.08}
```

I transform it into a DataFrame and copy to excel but the rendering is all over the place and not something I can work with (because it is a dictionary?)

What are the steps to make the output more user friendly?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

for transferring the data from dic to excel in python you can use panda :

```
import pandas as pd
dic1 = {"SPX": 1841.4, "SPTR":3302.66 ..., 'prev_day_rate': 0.08}
dic2 = {'SPX': 1841.4, 'SPTR': 3302.66,..., 'prev_day_rate': 0.08}
d = pd.DataFrame(data=dic1, index=[0])
d = (d.T)
print (d)
d.to_excel('dic1.xlsx')
```

also if you don't want to use panda, using import csv you can use any format you want

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like xlswriter and then you can iterate over the dictionary.

```
import xlsxwriter
# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses01.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
# Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
expenses = (
    ['Rent', 1000],
    ['Gas',   100],
    ['Food',  300],
    ['Gym',    50],
)
# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0
# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for item, cost in (expenses):
    worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost)
    row += 1
# Write a total using a formula.
worksheet.write(row, 0, 'Total')
worksheet.write(row, 1, '=SUM(B1:B4)')
workbook.close()
```

[image]
for more information : https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html